# how to access the request in a django custom authentication backend?

Tags: django, authentication

I want to do the following with django's authentication:

- Log incorrect log-in attempts
- Temporarily lock accounts after 'x' number of incorrect log-in attempts
- Log successful log-ins.

I thought a custom auth backend would be the solution.

I can do most of what i want, but I want to log the IP and REMOTE_HOST of the user making the attempt.

how can I access the request object in the auth backend?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The authentication backend can take any number of custom parameters for the `authenticate()` method. For example:

```
class MyBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, request=None):
         # check username, password
         if request is not None:
             # log values from request object
```

If you are calling authenticate in your own view, you can pass the request object:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def login(request):
    # discover username and password
    authenticate(username=username, password=password, request=request)
    # continue as normal
```

If you're using django's login view (or the admin login), you wont have the extra information. Put simply, you'll have to use your own custom login view.

Also, be careful when automatically locking accounts: you allow someone to deliberately lock one of your user's accounts (denial of service). There are ways around this. Also, make sure your log of incorrect attempts doesn't contain any attempted passwords.

Comment: i'm extending the ModelBackend - python doesn't allow me to overload methods does it? What would be a good way of achieving this? Just rename the 'authenticate' method and call that in my view?

Comment: what do i need to put in the login view? just copy the whole of the current contrib.auth login view? I don't understand because that method never calls 'authenticate'...

Comment: You can certainly overload in python. `contrib.auth` requires the backends to have an `authenticate` method, so you'll have to call it that.

Comment: Django's view calls `authenticate()` when validating its `AuthenticationForm` (in `contrib.auth.forms`). Django's login view also supports a number of other features which you wont need. It's not too difficult to put it in your own view, just call `authenticate` and login if all is good. Doing this in form validation is of course nicer, but you'll need to pass the request.

Comment: This awnser would still require me to hack into the admin because authenticate is called via a custom form which doesnt have a request attribute either..?

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Django, authenticate() accepts "request" as first parameter:

- optionally since Django 1.1
- required since Django 2.1

See:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#deprecated-features-1-11
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/