# django authentication without a password

Tags: django, authentication, openid

I'm using the default authentication system with django, but I've added on an OpenID library, where I can authenticate users via OpenID.  What I'd like to do is log them in, but it seems using the default django auth system, I need their password to authenticate the user.  Is there a way to get around this without actually using their password?

I'd like to do something like this...

```
user = ... # queried the user based on the OpenID response
user = authenticate(user) # function actually requires a username and password
login(user)
```

I sooner just leave off the `authenticate` function, but it attaches a `backend` field, which is required by login.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually logging in a user without password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787650/manually-logging-in-a-user-without-password).

Answer (score 28):

It's straightforward to write a custom authentication backend for this. If you create yourapp/auth_backend.py with the following contents:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class PasswordlessAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """Log in to Django without providing a password.

    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then add to your settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # ... your other backends
    'yourapp.auth_backend.PasswordlessAuthBackend',
)
```

In your view, you can now call authenticate without a password:

```
user = authenticate(username=user.username)
login(request, user)
```

Comment: This works great but beware - if you want to use regular auth in some situations, as well as no-password auth in others, be sure to prevent your new backend causing every attempt with a valid username to succeed - remember that all backends are tried when authenticate() is called. In mine I require a special token argument to be included to ensure that the caller of authenticate() really wanted no-password auth to work.

Comment: @Richard How you implemented regular auth and no password auth. I am trying to implement that but it is calling regular auth method.

Comment: Above code is not working with Django 2.1. It is not calling authenticate method of PasswordlessAuthBackend class. But it worls with Django 2.0

Comment: @SanketPatel I suspect that in newer Django versions the `def authenticate` must take a `request` parameter, as in [another answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55217797/263061).

Comment: @SanketPatel More info in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370236/263061.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit of a hack but if you don't want to rewrite a bunch of stuff remove the authenticate

```
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
login(request, user)
```

user would be your User object

Comment: That is one possible solution, but that doesn't get stored in the session, so if you open a new tab and go to the site, you have to log in again.

Comment: This WILL be saved in the session, and work in subsequent views. The only gotcha is that the backend you set must be included in the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting. I wish I could undo my downvote, but I can't.

Comment: @voodoogiant, I met exactly the same issue, that is the session is not stored. But weird enough,  the first 2 XHR requests could get session data from session-id correctly. But the later XHR request does not, and Django server set session-id in cookie to blank string in response. Do you know why? and how to solve that?

Answer (score 7):

In order to do authenticate without password, in your `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
# auth_backend.py implementing Class YourAuth inside yourapp folder
    'yourapp.auth_backend.YourAuth', 
# Default authentication of Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

In your `auth_backend.py`:

> NOTE: If you have custom model for your app then import from `.models` `CustomUser`

```
from .models import User 
from django.conf import settings

# requires to define two functions authenticate and get_user

class YourAuth:  

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

In your Views for custom login request:

```
# Your Logic to login user
userName = authenticate(request, username=uid)
login(request, userName)
```

For further reference, use the [django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/).

Comment: Thanks for formatting for better readability @OliviaStork

Comment: can I use this on just one app of my project, and not apply it to the rest of the project?

Comment: 'uid' is not defined. What are you refering to with 'uid'?

Comment: 'uid' is the custom parameter to store User ID in logic

Comment: @Timothyjames67 Yes you can make custom user model

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fix this by creating your own [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend) and adding it to the [`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS) setting.

There are some OpenID backends available already, so with a bit of searching you could save yourself the trouble of writing one.

Comment: I've had problems with django OpenID backends as they weren't compatible with Google's unique way of doing OpenID.  Anyway, like I said I already have a password-based backend and I just want to use OpenID in some cases--not switch to a strict OpenID backend.

Comment: @voodoogiant: depending on the keyword arguments the authentication backend is chosen. So if you use `openid_token` for your OpenID backend and `username` with `password` for your normal authentication system than they will both work.