# django allauth cant signup if new while logging user

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

i have used my code based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951026/django-allauth-logging-in-with-facebook-token-from-ios-device) i want to log user and if user is not registered then i want to signup with default account and social account like default link for login  for all auth does. this works fine when user is already signed up.

code from view.py

```
class mobile_facebook_login_without_signup(APIView):

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, format='application/json'):
        if request.method == "POST": # The method better be a POST
            access_token = request.DATA.get('access_token') # Get token
            email = request.DATA.get('email') # Get email
            print "email = " +str(email) + " - access_token = " +str(access_token)
            try:
                app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider="facebook")
                token = SocialToken(app=app, token=access_token)

                # Check token against facebook
                login = fb_complete_login(request, app, token)
                login.token = token
                login.state = SocialLogin.state_from_request(request)
                print "login = " +str(login)
                # Add or update the user into users table
                ret = complete_social_login(request, login)
                print "ret = " +str(ret)

                data = {}
                # Try to get username from email
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(email=email) # Get User
                    # Login the user from Django's perspective
                    #user.backend = 'django_tours.auth_backend.PasswordlessAuthBackend'
                    user.backend = 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend'
                    user = authenticate(email=user.email)
                    auth_login(request,user)
                except User.DoesNotExist,e:
                    return Response('failure: %s'%(e), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
                return Response( 'sign-in successful ', status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            except Exception,e:
                return Response('Failure: %s'%(e), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        else:
            return Response('failure', status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have figured it out, all i have to do was to add following return statement and it worked

```
    return Response(data={
        'success': True,
        'username': request.user.username,
        'email': email,
        'user_id': request.user.pk,
        }, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```