# How to authenticate users after running set_unusable_password?

Tags: python, django

I created a user with

```
 new_user = create_user(
            username=username, email=email, first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name)
new_user.set_unusable_password()
```

But the `authenticate()` returns `None` for that user

```
auth_user = authenticate(
            username=new_user.username, password=new_user.password)
```

Login fails for that user

```
AttributeError: "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'"
```

How should I go about authenticating these users?

Comment: You missed the brackets. new_user.set_unusable_password()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing a custom authentication backend that doesn't require password.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21263363/4742432):

You can then simply use your custom authenticate function:

```
auth_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `authenticate(**credential)` the user when the user having no password.

[`django.contrib.auth.authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) is to authenticate a given **username** and **password**.

So you should create [your own authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends) given only **username**. Basically the only authentication you need to do is to check if the user is in the database. But it is pretty obvious that the user is in the database. So alternatively, you can just fake the authentication process by setting the `user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` directly.

Followed by  [`login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) to login a given user.

> When you’re manually logging a user in, you must successfully authenticate the user with `authenticate()` before you call `login()`. `authenticate()` sets an attribute on the User noting which authentication backend successfully authenticated that user (see the backends documentation for details), and this information is needed later during the login process.

```
def autologin(request):

    # ...
    # ...
    # ...

    new_user = create_user(
        username=username,
        email=email,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name)
    user = authenticate(new_user)
    if user.is_authenticated():
        login(request, user)
    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

Comment: for the `user.backend` it is good if you can avoid hard coding the backend. and use the `django.conf.settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND` instead