# Authentication without a passwrod Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication

As the title states I'm trying to authenticate a user without a password. I've already used this: [django authentication without a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560182/django-authentication-without-a-password) to solve my problem with on of my apps (on Django 2.0), but I want to do the same thing in another app but It's on Django 2.1. When I do the same implementation my custom authenticate fuction is never called. Thus it doesn't work.

Current setup in auth_backend.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class PasswordlessAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """Log in to Django without providing a password.

    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

setup in settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
# auth_backend.py implementing Class PasswordlessAuthBackend inside yourapp folder
    'yourapp.auth_backend.PasswordlessAuthBackend', 
# Default authentication of Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

but when I try in my views

```
user = authenticate(username=user.username)
```

It never hits my custom authentication method. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my own issue thanks to documents here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

All I had to do was authetnicate function in auth_backend.py from

```
def authenticate(self, username=None):
```

to

```
def authenticate(self, request, username=None):
```

In the documentation it said you can also change the class delcaration not to include ModelBackend, but it worked either way.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid path to your Auth Backend in settings.py

```
yourapp.auth_backend.YourAuth
```

Should be

```
yourapp.auth_backend.PasswordlessAuthBackend
```

Comment: That's mb. I already had it correctly on my side of things. Just messed up copy and pasting

Answer (score 0):

can you try avoiding the default backend.

change

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
# auth_backend.py implementing Class PasswordlessAuthBackend inside yourapp folder
    'yourapp.auth_backend.PasswordlessAuthBackend', 
# Default authentication of Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

to

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
# auth_backend.py implementing Class PasswordlessAuthBackend inside yourapp folder
    'yourapp.auth_backend.PasswordlessAuthBackend', 
]
```

Comment: I actually solved my issue. All I had to do was add request as a paramter in my authenticate function