# Login user from different application into Django application

Tags: django, django-views

I have a use-case where I have to login a user from different application in my django application.

The user will click a button in the primary application where the user data like username, firstname, lastname and userid is sent to me as jwt token.

In my application I am decrypting the jwttoken and fetching the user data json and then using

```
django.contrib.auth import login
```

method to login the user and then sending the response

```
user = User.objects.get(user_name=user_name)
login(request, user)
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': "you are successfully logined in"}), content_type='application/json')
response.status_code = 200
return response
```

where in the primary application then the user is redirected to dashboard of my application whose view is

```
@login_required(login_url='/testserver/user/login/')
def dashboard(request):
     user = User.objects.get(user_name=request.user)
     return render(request, 'home.html', {'user':user})
```

The problem is that the user is redirected to `/testserver/user/login/` URL and if I remove it `@login_required(login_url='/testserver/user/login/')`, then i see that `request.user` is `AnonymousUser`.

How can I fix this to make it end to end working?

Comment: hi you have a type here user = User.objects.get(user_name=request.user) change it to user = User.objects.get(username=request.user).Maybe your problem is here.

Comment: No the problem is not there, because the request.user is coming as AnonymousUser

Comment: but the User models does not have a field (user_name) ?

Comment: ok, I had changed it but still getting the same error

Comment: user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)login(request, user)
            messages.success(request,"you are successfully logined in!")
            return redirect('the_url_of_dashbord')

Comment: could you please show your views.py for login_url ? i think you are loging a user with only a username that is so bad

Comment: Yes I am logging user with password, as custom login due to the requirements. I am following this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21263363/12847046

Comment: look at before login(request,user) you use user = User.objects.get(username=user_name) this means that you are just checking the username

Answer (score 0):

The `login()` function only sets the user on the current django session, so it would only be used by the application in which `login` was called.

For your use case, it seems like you have 2 django applications and need to use one as the authentication source for the other. I would suggest looking into [Django remote user support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/auth-remote-user/) and configuring it like that, or moving the login view to the main application but utilizing the first applications database as the truth source so you don't loose the current users ([Django multiple databases doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases)).

You could also look into some more proven methods to authenticate users in another application like [OpenId Connect](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc)

Comment: I don't think that @code-k has a completely different django project with different authentication backend and session middleware.